# Evaluating a particular Lebesgue integral

Tags: real-analysis

I would like to evaluate the Lebesgue integral $\int_{\Omega}x-y^2 \,dx\,dy$ using the level set definition of the Lebesgue integral. Here $\Omega = -\sqrt{x} < y < x, 0 < x < 1$.

It seems easy enough to handle the $y$ term if it's over the real line. Just realize that you're dealing with $\mu \{y: -y^2 > t\} = \mu \{y: y^2 < -t\} = \mu \{y: -y^2 > t\} = \mu \{y: |y| < \sqrt{-t}\}$, where $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure and $t$ is a real number. We can then use the definition of the Lebesgue measure of a ball to see that this equals $\pi t^2$. However, this is not the case, so I'm not quite sure what to do.

I think that the next step involves Fubini's theorem. However, I'm having difficulty getting the measure of $x$, since it doesn't look like we can use the definition of the Lebesgue measure of a ball.

Some hints would be appreciated here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Level set definition works for a nonnegative function. Thus, you cannot apply it to $\int xdxdy$ and $\int -y^2 dxdy$ separately. If correctly done, 
$$
\int_\Omega (x-y^2) dxdy = \int_0^1 dx\left(\int_{-\sqrt{x}}^{x} (x-y^2)dy\right)=\int_0^1 dx\left(\int_0^\infty \mu(y\in(-\sqrt{x},x)\;|\;x-y^2>t)dt\right).
$$
We can see that $$\mu(y\in(-\sqrt{x},x)\;|\;x-y^2>t) = \sqrt{x-t} + [\sqrt{x-t} \wedge x] $$is equal to $\sqrt{x-t}+x$ for $0<t<x-x^2$ and $2\sqrt{x-t}$ for $x-x^2 <t<x$. By integrating separately, we get
$$
\int_0^{x-x^2} \sqrt{x-t}+x\;dt + \int_{x-x^2}^x 2\sqrt{x-t}\;dt = \int^x_{x^2}\sqrt{t} dt + x^2(1-x) + 2\int_0^{x^2}\sqrt{t} dt = \frac{2}{3}x^{1.5} + x^2 -\frac{1}{3}x^3.
$$
Finally, the answer is $$
\int_0^1 \frac{2}{3}x^{1.5} + x^2 -\frac{1}{3}x^3dx = \frac{31}{60}.
$$
(Apply Fubini's theorem first, then 1-dimensional integral about $y$ is calculated using your method.)
If you want to apply level set method in 2-dimension directly, you should calculate
$$
\mu_2(x\in [0,1], y\in [-\sqrt{x},x]\;|\; x-y^2 >t ),
$$ which also requires Fubini's theorem to calculate 2-dimensional Lebesgue meausure.
(Note: We can see that $\int_{-\sqrt{x}}^x (x-y^2)dy = \frac{2}{3}x^{1.5} + x^2 -\frac{1}{3}x^3$ as expected.)

Comment: How do you move from the third part of the equality to the fourth?

Comment: $\mu$ is a 1-dimensional Lebesgue measure, so $\mu(y\in[-\sqrt{x},\sqrt{x}]\;|\;x-y^2>t) = \mu(y \;| \;|y|<\sqrt{x-t} ) = 2\sqrt{x-t}$ if $t\leq x$, and is $0$ if $t>x$.

Comment: What I don't understand is why you consider $y \in [-\sqrt{x}, \sqrt{x}]$.

Comment: Oh, I see my mistake.

Comment: I think you might have misread the question! $\Omega = -\sqrt{x} < y < x, 0 < x < 1$.

Comment: Can you explain why $\mu(y\in(-\sqrt{x},x)\;|\;x-y^2>t) = \sqrt{x-t} + [\sqrt{x-t} \wedge x]$ is equal to $\sqrt{x-t}+x$ for $0<t<x-x^2$ and $2\sqrt{x-t}$ for $x-x^2 <t<x$?

Comment: Here, $a\wedge b$ is used to denote $\min\{a,b\}.$ If $t < x-x^2$, then $\sqrt{x-t}>x$, so $[\sqrt{x-t}\wedge x] =x$ and vice versa.

Comment: One last question: why do you include the $[\sqrt{x-t}\wedge x]$ term when computing the measure? I don't understand the logic behind it.

Comment: The set whose measure we want to calculate is divided into positive and negative part. On the negative half, since $-\sqrt{x}<-\sqrt{x-t}<0$, it's equal to $(-\sqrt{x-t},0]$ giving the measure $\sqrt{x-t}$. On the positive half, $\sqrt{x-t}$ and $x$ are crossing, thus $[0, \sqrt{x-t}) \cap [0,x) = [0,  \sqrt{x-t}\wedge x)$ and its measure equals $\sqrt{x-t}\wedge x$. That's why I include $\sqrt{x-t}\wedge x$ in the expression.